# How to know if a Gradle dependency is present in the remote binary repository?

Tags: gradle, dependencies, fetch

I know that doing:

```
gradle dependencies
```

Let's you download (fetch) dependencies defined in the build.gradle to the local gradle cache folder.

Now, I would like to know if a given dependency actually exists in whatever repo I defined in the build.gradle without actually trying to download them.
Does anybody happen to know which is the task I should run for just checking that?
Thanks in advance community!

Comment: Public or private repo? Most of them have a web ui wiith a good enough search box as well.

Comment: Hi @RaGe, I guess it doesn't matter. The good about gradle cli is that it automagically infers the repo from where to download a dependency given the repos configured in the build.gradle. (I think it follows repo declaration order)
I do know that doing gradle dependencies will try to download the defined dependencies but I don't want to do that, I just want a task checking if the dependency actually exists remotely in any of the defined repos. Ahh, BTW I don't want to rely on external website, I need to use just gradle commands/tasks. Thanks!